# Exif data missing after post from android to server via json using php post

Tags: php, android, json

in my app, I am taking a picture with the camera in an intent. The file ist stored on the sd card. The onResult() method of the activity is giving the file to an other class Event which is creating a MyPic object:

```
class Event {

  public processResult(File f) {

    MyPic myPic = new MyPic(f);
    ExifHelper.setExif(f);
    sendImage(myPic);
  }

  private void sendImage(MyPic myPic) {

    try {
      JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
      jsonObject.put("myPic", myPic.getBase64());

      URL url = new URL("http://anUrl.de/test.php");

      byte[] data = jsonObject.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

      HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      conn.setConnectTimeout(10000);
      conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
      conn.setDoOutput(true);
      conn.setDoInput(true);
      conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");
      conn.setRequestProperty("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
      conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
      conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(data.length);
      conn.connect();

      OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
      os.write(data);
      os.flush();

      [...]
    } catch(JSONException e) {
      // Log.e(...)
    }
  }
}



class MyPic {

  public final File pic;

  public MyPic(File pic) {

    this.pic = pic;
  }

  public String getBase64() {

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Bitmap                bm   = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pic.getAbsolutePath());
    // Try 1:
    // bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    // bm.resize();
    // return Base64.encodeToString(baos.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);

    // Try 2:
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bm.getByteCount();
    bm.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);

    return buffer.array();
  }
}



public class ExifHelper {

  // Just an example
  public static void setAttribute(File f) throws IOException {

    ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(f.getAbsolutePath());
    exifInterface.setAttribute("Artist", "Foo");
    exifInterface.setAttribute("XPAuthor", "Foo");
    exifInterface.saveAttributes();
  }
}
```

After creating MyPic, setExif(File f) from a static class ExifHelper is called.
At last, the image is send with sendImage().

Here is the test.php:

```
<?php
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
print file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/test/image.jpg', base64_decode($json['pic']));
?>
```

The image on the sdcard contains the exif data "Artist":"Foo". I can download it via android device monitor and Windows 8.1 shows it.

If I try to read the tag via ExifInterface.getAttribute("Artist") or ExifInterface.getAttribute("XPAuthor") it returns null.

The created image on the server (debian) does not contain the tag.

I tried a lot things already but was not able to get it runnning. I also thought about setting the exif data with the PEL php library but the data is needed also on the phone and it seems to be stupid to do the job twice. Maybe the little php script I wrote clears the exifdata?

Could someone please help me out to get this running? Are there any alternatives?

Comment: 'sendImage();' AND 'private void sendImage(myPic)'. ????? And what is 'bm' ? What does it have to do with your picture?

Comment: Ups. Yeah I wrote the code with the editor here and missed that errors.

Comment: You should copy paste your code from your IDE to prevent this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is inconsistent. But to see is that you place your file in a Bitmap first. Bitmaps do not contain exif information. So you threw it away. Send the file itself. Don't convert it to Bitmap.

Comment: Feeling a little stupid. Shoud I have known this? I googled a little bit but found nothing about it. But it Worked. Converted the file directly to byte[] with FileInputStream.

Comment: Nothing stupid of course. Afterwards it all looks logical. Not before.